# Google Cloud Messaging Result.getSuccess() is null what does it mean?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Google Cloud Messaging returns `null` for `com.google.android.gcm.server.result` `getSuccess()` method but it assigns a `messageId` to a message. Also GCM returns `null` for `getErrorCodeName`.

What does it mean? Was message successfully sent?

`Result.toString()` looks like this: `[messageId=0:1475594652677091%46309dd1f9fd7ecd]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this [GitHub thread](https://gist.github.com/joekr/4197940), **if the message is successfully created, the `getMessageId()` returns the `messageId` and `getErrorCodeName()` returns `null`;** otherwise, `getMessageId()` returns `null` and `getErrorCodeName()` returns the code of the error.

So, I can say that the message was successfully sent.